# How to move a Google map search field

Tags: css, google-maps

I am trying to move the search field for google maps outside of the map itself and place it above it along side another form element but the ID (pac-input) that gives it its functionality keeps repositioning it back into the map. Does anybody know how to disable this rule while keeping the functionality?

Comment: Can you provide images to better explain your problem?

Comment: My lack of reputation doesn't let me upload images, basically the search bar at the top of the google map I want to move from that positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try following:

Take look at official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox), Then change the

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

To whatever you want, Like `TOP_RIGHT`to move a Google map search field